# Latex will not allow me to typeset apostrophe key?

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I'm trying to use the apostrophe key in math mode to write something like x' for "x prime" but I keep getting an error that says

```
"TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
'->\futurelet "
```

and

```
"Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!".
```

I didn't use to get this error and I'm not sure why it's happening now. I have updated my TeXShop but this error is still there.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think the error is not the prime, could you post a little example of your code?

Comment: Please, also add the precise error message you find in the log file.

Comment: the standard definition of `'` does not start with `\futurelet` so it seems you have a non standard definition which you hav enot shown.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `'` to be a loop. Judging by the small fragment of error message that you showed your definition appears to be something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\catcode`\'=13
\def'{\futurelet\tmp'''}

$x'$

\end{document}
```

which produces the error message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
'->\futurelet \tmp ''
                     '
l.8 $x'
       $
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

In this case (and probably your case) the definition does nothing useful so it should be deleted.  Note the `'->\futurelet` showing `'` expanding to something starting with `\futurelet`

Answer (score 0):

A MWE would be great.

Until then, `$'$` or `$\prime$` or `\ensuremath{'}` or `\ensuremath{\prime}` or `\textprime` should get you through.

Comment: if `x'` is looping as shown in the question `$'$` is likely to loop as well.